# Cakephp how to use between and mySQL date functions

Tags: mysql, date, cakephp, model

I would like to set the following query in Cakephp :

```
-- data in current month     
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE DATE(`created`) BETWEEN ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 0 MONTH)
```

I tried this, in my model Test.php :

```
$conditions['DATE(created) BETWEEN ? AND ?'] = array('ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY)', 'DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 0 MONTH)');
$data = $this->find('all', array($conditions))
```

but this does not work, because cakephp will add quotes...

Here is the sql output :

```
 SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATE(`created`) BETWEEN 'ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY)' AND 'DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 0 MONTH)';
```

How can I deal with mySQL date functions in cakephp ?

Comment: Why aren't writing your query directly and passing just parameter like 1 for 1 day ?

Comment: maybe you can suggest an example using Cakephp framework ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you must put the whole query in the array, like so:

```
$conditions['DATE(created) BETWEEN ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 0 MONTH)'];
```

Comment: Actually I had to set it like this : array_push($conditions, 'DATE(created) BETWEEN ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 0 MONTH)') so that it can fully works. your suggestion returned undefined index. Thanks